# Conditional increment of a partial value based on other field value in R dataframe

Tags: r, increment

I have a dataset where second column value (last digit) is to be incremented when ORDER_NUMBER is equal to previous ORDER_NUMBER.

For Example at line 4 the value of ORDER_ID should be 'VLNA2002' and at last line it should be 'VLNA1002'

I am tying to avoid using loop , thus pls suggest something which consumes less time in execution.

```
ORDER_NUMBER    ORDER_ID

1. a0ad93002NJ  VFOA1001
2. a0ah49003CA  TLNT4001
3. a0be91002CA  VLNA2001
4. a0be91002CA  VLNA2001
5. a0bf07002CA  TLNR1001
6. a0bs76001NC  TFOR4001
7. a0cf16003CA  TLNR4001
8. a0ez58002OR  VLNA1001
9. a0ez58002OR  VLNA1001

for(k in 2:totalcount){
    if(ORDER_NUMBER[k]==ORDER_NUMBER[k-1]) {
        ORDER_ID[k]= paste(
           substr(ORDER_ID[k],1,7),
           as.integer(substr(ORDER_ID[k],8,8))+1,
           sep="")
    }
}
```

would this work?

```
orderid=function(x){
    if(x<rowcount & (ORDER_NUMBER[x]==ORDER_NUMBER[x-1])) {
        ORDER_ID[x]=paste(substr(ORDER_ID[x],1,7),
        (as.integer(substr(ORDER_ID[x],8,8))+1),sep="")
    }
    x=x+1
}
orderid(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think this would work, first, the test data set

```
dd<-data.frame(
    orderid = c("VFOA1001","TLNT4001","VLNA2001",
        "VLNA2001","TLNR1001","TFOR4001",
        "TLNR4001","VLNA1001","VLNA1001"), 
    ordernumber = c("a0ad93002NJ","a0ah49003CA","a0be91002CA",
        "a0be91002CA","a0bf07002CA","a0bs76001NC","a0cf16003CA",
        "a0ez58002OR","a0ez58002OR")
)
```

Now we split up the order number. We take the first 4 characters as a prefix, and the last four as a number we can increment later.

```
ss<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(dd$orderid),""), function(x) 
    list(paste(x[1:4], collapse=""), as.numeric(paste(x[5:8], collapse="")))
)
prefix<-sapply(ss, '[[', 1)
index<-sapply(ss, '[[', 2)
```

Now we calculate how much the order number should change based on repeated order numbers

```
offset<-unlist(sapply(rle(as.character(dd$ordernumber))$lengths, seq.int))-1
```

And finally, we create new order IDs

```
neworderid<-paste(prefix, sprintf("%04d", index+offset), sep="")
cbind(dd, neworderid)
```

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, this runs swiftly and works even when increment is after 9 occurences.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #2: this results in what you asked for and should work for order number frequencies up to 999 (this limit is given by the format of the ORDER_ID column)

input:

```
totalcount <- read.table(header=T,text="
  ORDER_NUMBER    ORDER_ID
1. a0ad93002NJ  VFOA1001
2. a0ah49003CA  TLNT4001
3. a0be91002CA  VLNA2001
4. a0be91002CA  VLNA2001
5. a0bf07002CA  TLNR1001
6. a0bs76001NC  TFOR4001
7. a0cf16003CA  TLNR4001
8. a0ez58002OR  VLNA1001
9. a0ez58002OR  VLNA1001")
```

run the code

```
library(dplyr)                     #install dplyr package

result <- 
totalcount %.% 
group_by(ORDER_NUMBER) %.% 
mutate(NewID = substr(ORDER_ID,1,4)) %.%
mutate(count1 = 1:n()) %.%
mutate(count2 = as.numeric(substr(ORDER_ID,5,5))*1000) 

result$ORDER_ID <- with(result, paste(NewID,count1+count2,sep=""))
result <- result[,-c(3:5)]
```

output:

```
> result
Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
Groups: 
   ORDER_NUMBER ORDER_ID
1  a0ad93002NJ VFOA1001
2  a0ah49003CA TLNT4001
3  a0be91002CA VLNA2001
4  a0be91002CA VLNA2002
5  a0bf07002CA TLNR1001
6  a0bs76001NC TFOR4001
7  a0cf16003CA TLNR4001
8  a0ez58002OR VLNA1001
9  a0ez58002OR VLNA1002
```

Comment: You might get into trouble with this solution if an order number appears more than 9 times, right?

Comment: Thanks beginnerR for your assitance, at third line where mutate is used, it throws.'Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: @user3609268 I just retested my code and i dont get any error message. (i am running R 3.1.0 and dplyr 0.1.3 on win7)